# Best battery configuration: 1s1p vs 3s1p vs 1s3p?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-polymer

I’m designing a product prototype using a single board computer (like a Raspberry Pi) that requires an 8-18V DC supply. It has to become battery powered, so I’m looking into the best possible configuration. Besides the SBC, another component in the device requires a 9V supply. The SBC currently consumes about 200mA when powered from 12.6V and we expect about 1000mA peaks from the 9V device.

The simplest battery configuration seems 3 LiPo’s in series. I’d need an additional buck converter for the 9V rail. What worries me more is balanced gauging and charging of the cells. Compared to single cell LiPo charging it seems rather complicated and I’m having a hard time finding a simple yet effective (pair of) ICs that do the job without having to spend too much time setting things up. For reference, I was quite overwhelmed by TI’s bq40z60 all in one solution. Very nice but too complicated for the time and budget I have.

I could also use a single cell pack with high C rating and boost it up to 9V. Add a simple charge IC and single cell gauge like I used before in other designs and done with it. Of course the run time would be significantly lower than with 3s1p but so much quicker to build!

And I guess 1s3p would increase the runtime again but also complicate the charging and gauging, so I don’t think that is really a good option.

What would you do in a case like this?

Comment: I'd like to see a lot less time spent discussing your own mental travels around the barn, so to speak, and a lot more time spent documenting your exact needs. I see a 12.6 V supply at 200 mA (assumed average) without any idea of its peak requirements and a 9 V supply where I know the peak (1 A) but have no idea about its average or even if it is completely off for a while. Write as much detail as possible about what is going on, with duty cycles as appropriate. And a lot less about your own machinations about it.

Comment: Define exact power W and energy E and time, h  first!  Then Wh battery capacity then     Vmin-max options with efficiency and cost  budget then Make or Buy!